# Fiddler shown that my javascript file is not found, even though it's really there and works like expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fiddler

This is the line in Default.aspx that I included in my javascript file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../MyFiles/JavaScript/JavaScript.js" ></script>
```

While testing the web with Fiddler, it keeps on saying that my JavaScript.js file is not found (404 error) even though it's really there and works like expected. Any help or hint would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean when you say "works like expected"?

If Fiddler shows a 404, then either the server returned a 404, or you configured a rule in Fiddler (e.g. "Block JavaScript" on Fiddler's **Filters** tab).

Comment: I created some function in that JavaScript.js file and that function works, despite the fact that Fiddler said that JavaScript.js isn't found (404 Error).

Comment: That implies that the function in question exists in another place. You can see what JavaScript files IE successfully loaded by hitting F12 and clicking over to the SCRIPT tab.

Comment: It can't be. How can I type 1 function at two different places? The page works like expect, however, that Fillder msg kind of worrying me.

Comment: You can see what JavaScript files IE successfully loaded by hitting F12 and clicking over to the SCRIPT tab.